# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.

[image: Alexander Galkin]
[image: Rory]
[image: Mad Scientist]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections once you graduate.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

**[EDIT]**: Please welcome your newest moderator, **Tiago Cardoso!**

Comment: Tiago. Welcome and thank you for contributing!

Comment: Thanks, @MarkPhillips! I'm wide open for comments and suggestions. I had a great chat with J a few days ago where he presented me our duties specifically in pmse and I hope to contribute as much as I can, always looking forward to have our community going official!

Answer (score 5):

Thanks again!  I'm looking forward to seeing this grow and have been impressed with the thought-provoking great questions and answers submitted on this site.  We have a great pool of leaders here in the main body of contributors, and I've found the information invaluable.

Answer (score 4):

I am honored and look forward to working with the other moderators and the community to make this a great resource for project management questions and answers.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for inviting me. I'll try to be honest with the community and help turning our site into a valuable resource for professional project managers.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the honor of being part of this elite squad!

When Aarthi contacted me, I told her that we already got great mods... but still would be glad to help wherever I can.